# List of the process definition id from modeler Id in activiti

Tags: scala, activiti

In Activiti,we can edit the model and redeploy it but each time it is expecting different process definition id in the activiti modeler.

Is it possible to get the deployed processDefinitions from modeler id through RepositoryService.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such Rest API to query this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my question,

```
    var processEngine: ProcessEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine()
    val repositoryService: RepositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService
    /** This will delete the deployed process and its processDefinition and its cascade data from activiti database **/
     repositoryService.deleteDeployment(deploymentId,true)
```

This helps to have the same process definition Id whenever the model is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You do want a new process definition id every time you do a deployment, as you want to start process instances with the latest and keep old ones running against the old versions.

What's the use case you're trying to tackle here?

Comment: as I am making the changes for same process and redeploying , each time it will create new process definition id. One thing i want to know is whenever i'm changing the model it's not creating the versions for process definition id.can you tell me the reason for not getting versions.

Comment: I wish to add one more question to this comment.If I am have list of process Definition Ids for the same model with different versions like
        (Test:1:422504,Test:2:315017)

 and if i want to start the process by custom Api,i need to pass the process Definition Key.In that case,how can i get the latest process definition id.

Comment: * A new version is only created when you actually *deploy* a model. When you simply edit a model, without deploying it, there is no new version. Deploying a process definition is something you do when your model is good to go (unit tested and such) and you want to put it live.

* when you call startProcessInstanceByKey, it's always the latest version of the process definition for that key that is started